# Apache HttpResponse getting unformatted String instead of XML

Tags: java, apache, servlets, ldap, httpresponse

I have some Java code on a servlet to perform an LDAP lookup:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(theURL);
HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
InputStream in = getResponse.getEntity().getContent();
String encoding = "UTF-8";
String body = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
```

When implemented in Javascript, the response is an XML-style string along the lines of

```
<result>
<firstName>Bob</firstName>
<lastName>Smith</lastName>
<email>bobsmith@example.com</email>
</result>
```

Which was easy to parse. In Java, however, I get "BobSmithbobsmith@example.com", with no separators between values. The LDAP must return the necessary information because I get what I need with the JS implementation; is there a way I can get a parsable result from the `HttpResponse` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an "accept" header with request. Maybe the server sends plain text by default.

```
getRequest.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/xml");
```

[OR if that doesn't work]

```
getRequest.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "text/xml");
```